# Adapting ANT scripts for updating EAR file to Maven

Tags: maven, ant

I have an Ant script for automating a few tasks that are not build related by mainly as updates to the EAR file. These include calling SoapUI exe for some web services, unpacking the EAR file modifying a few classes and repacking it.

Now, for some reason I would like to do the same using maven scripts. From going through Stack Overflow and maven tutorial, I find that this can be replicated using Ant plugins inside maven. Also, I could not find direct substitutes for unpacking the EARs or calling executables in maven. This scripts will not have anything to do with the standard build process that maven is meant for and only caters to some cleanup or update of already deployed EAR.

So how do I go about this? Use Ant plugins inside maven or is there a better maven way to do this?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

This may be an incomplete answer but -

1. Maven is more of a framework and it's going to want to build your application.  What it will *not* do is modify source.  It *will* process source files (.java, .ear, whatever) and put them in a `target/` directory.  Of course anything is possible (re: hackable) but this is off the rails as far as Maven is concerned if you want in place modification of source - besides, isn't the point of source that it's source, and if you're automating a task that should be part of your build, deploy, startup, etc.?
2. [Maven resource filtering](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/filter.html) is how to process a source file and stamp dynamic information into your resources.
3. If you can provide more information regarding how you are processing your .ear files exactly you can possibly put together the pieces in the Maven process resources phase using existing plugins.  Worst case you can write your own plugin.

Comment: Thanks. My exact requirements are as I mentioned - replace a few classes in the EAR file and execute SOAPUI. I col do this in Ant using unzip and exec tasks. Can I do the same in maven as a standalone code just doing this?